# Outlook 2007 VBA/Macro

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, macros, vba

I am a very amateur user new to macros and VBA. My problem is that I recive
online orders to which I need to click an auto generated unique order
hyperlink to confirm receipt of the order within a specified time period.

This is a mundane task having to be on 'standby' and was wondering if there
was a way to have this link automatically clicked when the email arrives.
Just to reiterate the link has a unique reference and is different on each
email.

Please bear in mind that I am a very basic user and would probably require
step by step instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Automatically clicking on the link rather defeats the purpose of the vender sending out a time-limted URL, doesn't it?

If you really want to do this, I think it's possible; but I don't think it's entirely straight-forward.  The task is simplified if there is only one URL in the message, or if the URL you are interested in is first (or last).  The "automatically clicking" would be done by doing an HTTP GET using the XmlHttpRequest object provided with IE.

I'm not providing any VBA code because 1) I don't want to take the time to work it up, and 2) I'm not sure it's the right thing to be doing anyway.